# Verify that an ellipse has four vertices.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, self-learning

Verify that an ellipse has four vertices.

The ellipse is given by $$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

And I took $$x=a\cos t$$ and $$y=b \sin t$$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$

Please can someone help me how to verify this?

Comment: What does it mean to have a "vertex" of an ellipse?  The definitions I have found indicate that an ellipse has only two.

Comment: I only know that a vertex of a curve $\gamma $ in $\Bbb R^2$ is a point where its signed curve has a stationary point $\partial \kappa_s/\partial t=0$ @abiessu

Comment: Then under that definition, it should be easy to find $t$ such that ${\partial x\over \partial t}=0$ or ${\partial y\over \partial t}=0$, given the parametric equations you have identified.

Comment: $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}= -a\sin t$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}=b\cos t$ isnt it? And then at what points are these fractions zero? Icannot find this:( @abiessu

Comment: Simplify to $\cos t=0, \sin t=0$.  At what values of $t$ do either of these equations apply?

Comment: Dont know at this time:( @abiessu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Consider the values $t=\frac {k\pi}2$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$ and the functions $\cos t,\sin t$.  Are there any values of $k$ such that $\cos \frac {k\pi}2=0$?  What about $\sin \frac {k\pi}2=0$?

Further hint:

We can separate the two partial derivatives $\partial x\over \partial t$ and $\partial y\over \partial t$ and get values satisfying either one of them according to the definition you are claiming, so consider the following:

$$\cos \frac \pi 2=\cos \frac {(2k+1)\pi}2=0$$

This covers two of your four "ellipse vertices".  Where are the other two?

Comment: Yes, k is the multiple of $2$. Isnt it?

Comment: @B11b: for which function, $\cos$ or $\sin$?  Note that they have different results for each $k$.

Comment: Hmm.. Okay? I need to find four values of $k$. Right?

Comment: $k=1, 3$ and what else?

Comment: But I wrote the values of $k$ for $\cos$. This values dont satisfy $\sin$ :(

Comment: Have you plugged any of these values into a calculator?  Note that we have $\sin {(4k)\pi\over 2}=\sin 0^\circ = 0$.

Comment: I have used "wolframalpha.com"

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Note that separating the partial derivatives and considering that each has its own solution(s) is acceptable given the definition you started with.

Comment: k=0, and 1. Right?

Comment: Yes, and you also found $k=3$, and I think that $k=2$ is valid giving you the four values that you are interested in.

Comment: That is $k=0, 1, 2 ,and 3$. that's all?

Comment: That is correct.  :-)  Of course, note that $\cos {5\pi\over 2}=\cos {\pi\over 2}=0$, which is another way of saying that these four values repeat with period $4$.

Comment: Since k has four values, the ellipse has four vertices.

Comment: Thank you for helping:) you struggled to explain the answer much because of me.

Comment: As long as it was helpful to you, it is worth it.  :-)

Comment: Hmm.. Okay, got it:)

Comment: There're simpler ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that
$$k=\frac{x'y''-x''y'}{((x')^2+(y')^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}.$$
You'll get
$$k'(t)=-\frac{3\sin(t)cos(t)(a^2-b^2)}{(a^2\sin^2t+b^2\sin^2t)^{\frac{5}{2}}}.$$
Wich is zero iff $\sin t=0$ or $\cos t=0$.